# Running docker containers sequentially

Tags: database, docker, deployment, devops

I have two containers. The first is the database. The second is the application. Both are in different docker containers.
The problem is that the database takes a very long time to deploy. The application starts quickly. I want to run the application only when the database is deployed.

```
I used for the database:
 healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U postgres -d RPLMCAPP"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 10
      start_period: 10s

I used for app:
wait-for-it.sh
```

It doesn't work.